# ASP.NET creating RSS feed, no error but no data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rss

OK for the record, I'm MUCH more familiar with Java and RnR than any .NET.  I have fixed a few bugs in a function here and there and Googled a few new "features" here and there but it's not my expertise.  OK cavets out of the way, here's my issue, I need to create a RSS feed for our site built in ASP.NET.   Google turned up a few solutions, but I used this one as an example:
http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Creating-an-RSS-Feed-with-ASP-Net-Written-in-C-Sharp/

Oddly, I get it all to work with no errors that I can see but I only get a blank page when I run it.  I've tested the SQL, it works and returns the rows I want but I don't know how to diagnose if it's connecting to the DB or not or why it's not returning anything.  Here's the code:

asp.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Xml;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Diagnostics;


       //Class for returning RSS feed Data

   public partial class rss : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string sSource;
        string sLog;
        string sEvent;
        sSource = "RSS Feed";
        sLog = "Application";
        sEvent = "Database Connectiont";
       // Connect to the Database
       SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=events;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=wa;Password=password;");
       // Retrieve the SQL query results and bind it to the Repeater
       const string SQL_QUERY = "SELECT EventName, Comments, URL, StartDate FROM event WHERE SaleDateTo > getdate() AND SaleDateFrom < getdate() AND redirecttourl is not null ORDER BY EventDate";
       SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL_QUERY, myConnection);
       bool IsDbAvailable = true;
       try {
           myConnection.Open();
           rptRSS.DataSource = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
           rptRSS.DataBind();
           myConnection.Close();
           }
           catch {
                IsDbAvailable = false;
                if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sSource))
                        EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource,sLog);
            }
        finally {
            myConnection.Close();
        }     
    }

    protected string FormatForXML(object input)
    {
       string data = input.ToString(); //cast input to string

       // replace those characters disallowed in XML documents
       data = data.Replace("&", "&amp;");
       data = data.Replace("\"", "&quot;");
       data = data.Replace("'", "&apos;");
       data = data.Replace("<", "&lt;");
       data = data.Replace(">", "&gt;");

       return data;
    }
}
```

rss.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page language="c#" CodeFile="rss.aspx.cs" ContentType="text/xml" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="rss"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<asp:Repeater id="rptRSS" runat="server">

  <HeaderTemplate>
    <rss version="2.0">
      <channel>
        <title>TA On-Sale Feed</title>
        <link>http://www.website.com/rss.aspx</link>
        <description>All events current on-sale</description>
  </HeaderTemplate>

    <itemTemplate>
    <event>
    <title><%#FormatForXML(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"EventName"))%>
    </title>
    <description>
    <%#FormatForXML(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comments"))%>
    </description>
    <link>http://order.ticketalternative.com<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url")%>
    </link>
    <eventdate>
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StartDate")%>
    <eventdate>
    </event>
    </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
          </channel>
        </rss>
      </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to use the built in [`SyndicationFeed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill your result set into a DataTable/Dataset using SQLDataAdpter and then assign the Dataset/Table to rtpRSS.DataSource.

Comment: SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL_QUERY, myConnection);
     DataSet events = new DataSet();
     adapter.Fill(events, "Events");
     rptRSS.DataSource = adapter;
     rptRSS.DataBind();